# Scripting an "open image" button input for image/env. textures?

Tags: scripting, node-editor, image

Is there a way to script out a normal image/environment texture node with the exception of an "open image" button input that can be plugged into a node group and have that button actually be displayed outside the groupnode? Any alternative would of course be acceptable  as well, but from my research I've found the only way to enable such function is to use a script. Thanks.

[image: -]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve by doing so?

Comment: I want to achieve extra node simplification and customization of material node groups; if you were trying to make a material setup which involved applying multiple textures which could also have specific texture coordinates, you could simplify that into a node group using the "open image" input, connecting it into a groupnode input node, and have all the texture coordinates already set up and the "open image" button at free node group display for easy customization.

Comment: Unfortunately this can't be done using python scripting, you will have to edit blender's source code or suggest this to the developers.

Comment: Well thanks for an answer then, would still be really nice if the developers integrated it in, or if there was a way to integrate this in by self. I guess current simplification works well enough for now.